# Pythonic way to add values to a dict inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, cisco

I have a class containing a dictionary and I'm pushing it to a Cisco APIC:

```
class Tenant:

    def __init__(self, apic, tenant_name, descr):
        self.apic = apic
        self.tenant_name = tenant_name
        self.descr = descr

        #can this be tidied away?
        self.dn = 'uni/tn-' + tenant_name
        self.rn = 'tn-' + tenant_name

        self.payload = {"fvTenant":{"attributes":{"descr":self.descr,"dn":self.dn,"name":self.tenant_name,"rn":self.rn}}}
```

The values for 'dn' and 'rn' use the same input value except I'm prefixing 'uni/tn-' and 'tn-' respectively.

Is there a more pythonic way to add those values to the dictionary - ie. with fewer lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

if having the extra attributes annoys you, you could always just build the "dn" and "rn" stuff when you build the dictionary

```
[snip]
   "attributes" : {
      "dn" : "uni/tn-" + tenant_name,
      "rn" : "tn-" + tenant_name,
[snip]
```